# Incomplete gamma functions: can this code get any faster in cython, C, or Fortran?

Tags: python, c, performance, fortran, cython

As part of a large piece of code, I need to calculate arrays of incomplete gamma functions.  For example, I need a function that returns (the log of) (gamma(z + m, a, inf)/m!) for m in [0, m_max], for various values of m_max (typically around 400), z, and a.  I need to do this quickly.  Currently, this step is the the slowest in my code by around a factor of ~2.  However, the full code takes ~a day to run, so reducing the computation time of this step by 2 would save me a lot of wall time.

I am using the following cython code for the calculation:

```py
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from mpmath import mp

sp_max = 5000 

def log_factorial(k):
    return np.sum(np.log(np.arange(1., k + 1., dtype=np.float)))

log_factorial_ary = np.vectorize(log_factorial)(np.arange(sp_max))

gamma_mem = mp.memoize(mp.gamma)
gammainc_mem = mp.memoize(mp.gammainc)

def gammainc_up_fct_ary_log(np.int m_max, np.float z, np.float a):
    cdef np.ndarray gi_list = np.zeros(m_max + 1, dtype=np.float)    
    gi_list[0] = np.float(gammainc_mem(z, a))
    cdef np.ndarray i_array = np.arange(1., m_max + 1., dtype=np.float)
    cdef Py_ssize_t i 
    for i in np.arange(1, m_max + 1):
        gi_list[i] = (i_array[i-1] - 1. + z)*gi_list[i-1]/i + np.exp((i_array[i-1] - 1. + z)*np.log(a) - a - log_factorial_ary[i])
    return gi_list
```

As an example, when I call `gammainc_up_fct_ary_log(400,-0.3,10.0)` it takes around ~0.015-0.025 seconds.  I would like to speed this up by at least a factor of 2 (or, ideally, as fast as possible).

Is there a clear way to speed up this computation using cython?  If not, would C or Fortran be significantly faster?  If so, what is the fastest way to write this function in that language and then call the code from python (the rest of my code is written in python/cython).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You compute `factorial_ary` but do not appear to use it.  Your computation of `log_factorial_ary` is expressed compactly, but it is grossly repetitive.  Still, as long you load the module only once and then call `gammainc_up_fct_ary_log()` repeatedly, the one-time module initialization code is not going to factor in to your per-call timing.

Comment: I removed `factorial_ary`.  Indeed, I only load the module once (then call the function `gammainc_up_fct_ary_log` many times), so I was not careful about optimizing `log_factorial_ary`.

Comment: How is the memory consumption of you job?  Memoization for a function that takes a pair of floating-point arguments is a bit dicey.  It *might* be a big win, but if you miss on exact floating-point equality then you could be clogging up memory with a bunch of never-reused results.  Managing all that could be costly.  Even if you're hitting, are you hitting *enough* for the memoization to pay for its overhead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several big issues in your cython version:

1. `i_array` is useless, you can safely replace `i_array[i-1]` by just `i`
2. You're not getting the most of cython. If you have a look to the output of `cython -a` on your code, you'll see that cython is just generating calls to the C-API, while you need calls to C code to have it run fast.

Here is an example of what you could achieve (incomplete, but the speedup is already great)

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from mpmath import mp

cdef extern from "math.h":
    double log(double x) nogil
    double exp(double x) nogil

sp_max = 5000 

def log_factorial(k):
    return np.sum(np.log(np.arange(1., k + 1., dtype=np.float)))

factorial_ary = np.array([np.float(mp.factorial(m)) for m in np.arange(sp_max)])
log_factorial_ary = np.vectorize(log_factorial)(np.arange(sp_max))

gamma_mem = mp.memoize(mp.gamma)
gammainc_mem = mp.memoize(mp.gammainc)

def gammainc_up_fct_ary_log(m_max, z, a):
    return gammainc_up_fct_ary_log_impl(m_max, z, a)

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef gammainc_up_fct_ary_log_impl(int m_max, double z, double a):
    cdef double[::1] gi_list = np.zeros(m_max + 1, dtype=np.float)
    gi_list[0] = gammainc_mem(z, a)
    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    for i in range(1, m_max + 1):
        t0 = (i - 1. + z)
        t1 = (i - 1. + z)*log(a) - a
        gi_list[i] = t0*gi_list[i-1]/i + exp(t1 - log_factorial_ary[i])
    return gi_list
```

running this code gives me:

```
python -m timeit -s 'from ff import gammainc_up_fct_ary_log' 'gammainc_up_fct_ary_log(400,-0.3,10.0)'
```

10000 loops, best of 3: 132 usec per loop

while your version hardly gives:

```
python -m timeit -s 'from ff import gammainc_up_fct_ary_log' 'gammainc_up_fct_ary_log(400,-0.3,10.0)'
```

100 loops, best of 3: 2.44 msec per loop

Comment: This is great! Now, the slow point of the code seems to be the evaluation of `mp.gammainc` itself when evaluating on new values of z and a.  I find that a typical evaluation takes  ~1 msec.  Is it possible to speed up this evaluation so that, when evaluating on new values of z and a, `gammainc_up_fct_ary_log_impl` would take ~0.1 msec (similar to when using memoized values)?